# How do you automatically set infiniband mode to connected?

Tags: networking, kernel

I'm setting up an Infiniband network in 18.04LTS server. The ib0 interface comes up without problems during boot but it comes up in "datagram" mode. I would like this to be configured so that it automatically comes up in connected mode.

Obsolete documentation suggests using pre-up scripts but netplan doesn't appear to support this sort of thing.

How do I configure ib0 to automatically come up in connected mode in Ubuntu Server 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

Since `netplan` does not support the `pre-up` scripts, you do have two options here:

1. #### Get rid of `netplan`

   Modify */etc/default/grub* and add `netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=true` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. Then run `update-grub`.

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=true"
   ```

   After a reboot */etc/network/interfaces* is used again.
2. #### Use `networkd` as `netplan`'s `renderer`

   Basically, it is `networkd-dispatcher` which will provide the functionality to call scripts. A detailed description can be found [here](https://netplan.io/faq#use-pre-up-post-up-etc-hook-scripts).